# Zsh: Is it possible to disable history expansion inside double quotes?

Tags: zsh, history-expansion

Is it possible to disable history expansion inside double quotes?

I do not want history expansion to be completely disabled, as I still use it, but I see no reason to expand the history inside a string ...

An example of my desired behavior:

```
$ echo "Hello!"
Hello!
$ !!
Hello!
```

Comment: `echo "Hello\!"`. Backslash ("`\ `") flips the "I am special" bit on `\ `.

Comment: @waltinator I know, but I do not want to escape it. I also dislike how the behavior is different between scripts and my interactive shell.

Comment: `echo 'Hello!'`.

Comment: @waltinator You're so clever.

Comment: how about in `echo "$(echo !!; echo ";;")"`? Do you consider that `!!` to be inside double quotes?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas It's obviously not inside a double quote IMO. It has opened a new subshell at that point, and we can even start a new double quote: `echo "$(echo "hi")"`